# Creating instance depending on enum parameter

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, factory

For example I have classes `Apple`, `Orange` , `Banana` , etc.. inherited from `Fruit` . Also I have `enum Fruits`

```
enum Fruits
{
    Apple,
    Orange,
    Banana
}
```

I want to create correct instance depending on `enum` parameter.

I know about simple factory.

```
public Fruit CreateFruit(enum Fruits fruits)
{
    switch (fruits)
    {
        case Apple:
            return new Apple();
        case Orange:
            return new Orange();
        case Banana:
            return new Banana();
    }
}
```

But this method violates the Open-Closes Principle (OCP), so are there better solutions?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256883/discussion-on-question-by-iliya-belan-creating-instance-depending-on-enum-parame); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

As a general observation, avoid `enum` types in C#. From an object-oriented perspective, there's no reason to have them, as explained by Martin Fowler in [Refactoring](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/refactoring). This book suggests that 'type codes' (as it's called in the book, which has Java examples) are a *code smell*, and suggests various refactorings/design changes that are more object-oriented - essentially making good use of polymorphism instead.

In addition to that, C# `enum` types aren't type-safe. At run time they're just glorified integers, and it's entirely possible that a type like `Fruits` may actually have the value `42`.

All that said, however, [at the boundaries, applications aren't object-oriented](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/31/AttheBoundaries,ApplicationsareNotObject-Oriented) anyway. You often run into situations where you receive data from the outside, and you'd like to translate it into a polymorphic type like `Fruit`. Even if an `enum` may not be the best way to model that, you may receive external input that suggests which type of data is in effect. You may receive a CSV file or JSON object where the type is indicated as a string; e.g. `"apple"`, `"orange"`, or `"banana"`. Alternatively, you may receive integer codes such as `1`, `2`, and `3`.

What remains now is a [parsing problem](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/). You are, however, running into a variation of [the expression problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem), because, regardless of how you slice or dice the problem, a primitive input type like a string or an integer implies a [set partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set). For example, if your input identifies the type as a string, you have an implicit partition of all strings into `"apple"`, `"orange"`, `"banana"`, and their [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)): all other strings.

Practically, it means that a parser may look like this:

```
public Fruit? TryParse(string candidate)
{
    switch (candidate)
    {
        case "apple":
            return new Apple();
        case "orange":
            return new Orange();
        case "banana":
            return new Banana();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Notice that you have four cases, not three.

If you add a new subtype, you'd have to change this implementation.

Now, there are ways to move this kind of problem around. For example, [Code Complete](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/code-complete) suggests a technique called *table-driven methods*. You could, for example, implement your parser based on a dictionary:

```
public Fruit? TryParse(string candidate)
{
    if (dict.TryGetValue(candidate, out var fruit))
    {
        return fruit;
    }
    return null;
}
```

While this seems to solve the original problem with the [Open-Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) (OCP), you still need to populate that dictionary *somewhere*.

You may decide to populate such a dictionary by reading configuration data from somewhere (e.g. a configuration file), but beware of the [The Configuration Complexity Clock](https://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2012/05/configuration-complexity-clock.html) or the [inner-platform effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect). Is it actually worth it to go to such lengths?

The five SOLID principles are all guidelines that help you address certain problems related to maintenance of code bases (see e.g. [APPP](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/appp)). If you don't have those problems, there's no reason to apply a concept like the OCP.

You'd typically like to avoid an anti-pattern like [Shotgun Surgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_surgery), so you don't want to have `switch/case` expressions all over your code base. On the other hand, refactoring to a single parser at least follows the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) in that the only reason you'd have to change the parser is if the enumeration of subtypes changes. Furthermore, there's only one place you'd need to implement such a change.

Finally, the conclusions posited by the expression problem has been challenged. For a C# perspective on that, see [my reading of the paper Extensibility for the Masses](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2021/07/12/a-reading-of-extensibility-for-the-masses).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this is not an actual answer, just a *very* long comment about a question which should have been closed because of being to opinion-based in the first place.

As with many principles, the Open-Closed-Principle is rather a *guideline* than a fix *law*. Sometimes you need to *bend* the rules a bit, sometimes you need to *break* them. The practical question rather is: *where* do you do that. You cannot extend a system without *any* kinds of modification to it. Even a config-file - e.g. for a DI-container - is some sort of code which you need to change in order to modify your system.

Having said this you usually *need* to apply the changes to your system *somewhere*. In your case you can of course introduce further abstractions - e.g. a factoy-pattern or even an abstract factory. You can rely on a DI-container, or some kind of a naming-convention and some reflection to instantiate your types. However that just introduces a further level of abstraction without solving the actual question: **how to *define* which fruit to create?**

Depending on how often and extensivly you extend your system, your naive switch may be pretty fine. If you never add further types, why bother about the factory-method? But even *if* you add some types, you need to change only the factory, not the rest of your system, so **the rest is still closed about modifications**. One may read the principle also as "there's exactly **one single place** for createing types in my code, so the rest of my system is completely independend on them". Of course that place violates some principles, but that may be okay - in particular when this gluecode is auto-generated as in a DI-container for instance.

So long story short: you have allways a trade-off here between *practical use* and *abstract design*. There's no general way how to balance between these.

To give this *comment* a bit more of an *answer* - even an opinion-based one, I add my favourit idea here. Instead of hard-coding the types that relate to your enum, you can introduce some convention, e.g. forcing enum-value and type-name to be equivalent:

```
enum Fruits
{
    Apple,
    Banana,
    Orange
}

Fruit CreateFruit(Fruits fruit)
{
    var typeName = fruit.ToString();
    ...
    // apply assembly-qualified typeName
    ...
    return (Fruit) Activator.CreateInstance(typeName); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to avoid such a factory while using an enum. But you could replace the enum with an factory object, something like:

```
public interface IFruit { }
public class Apple: IFruit { }
public class Orange : IFruit { }

public interface IFruitFactory
{
    IFruit Create();
}

public class AppleFactory : IFruitFactory
{
    public static readonly AppleFactory Instance = new();
    public IFruit Create() => new Apple();
}
public class OrangeFactory : IFruitFactory
{
    public static readonly OrangeFactory Instance = new();
    public IFruit Create() => new Orange();
}
```

With this pattern you would pass around a `IFruitFactory` instead of a fruit enum, allowing anyone to easily constrct a fruit from it. If you want to add a Banana you just create a new `BananaFactory`.

But I would recommend being pragmatic. The problem with switch-methods as in your example is when someone forgets to add a case when adding a new value, putting the factory close to the enum declaration, i.e. in the same file, help reduce this risk.

As is often the case, rules like 'open-close principle' are general recommendations, but you need to know why they exist and when they are applicable. Trying to dogmatically follow all design principles is just not a good idea.

Comment: "If you want to add a Banana you just create a new BananaFactory." But how would you determine of you need a `BananaFactory`, instead of an `AppleFactory`? The abstract factory doesn't help in indicating which type to create.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain At some point in the program there need to be a decision about what fruit to use. You would use `BananaFactory.Instance` in the same place you would use `Fruit.Banana`. So in some sense this just provide an enum with more capabilities. If you need to *list* all the fruits you are kind of back at the original problem, unless you want to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

in order to make instance of each class based on enum value, you should use attribute. for example you can add this attribute :

```
  public class FruitAttribute : Attribute
  {
      public Type Type { get; }

      public FruitAttribute(Type type)
      {
         Type = type;
      }
  }
```

then you should define value of this attribute for your enum:

```
  enum Fruits
  {
      [FruitAttribute(typeof(Apple))]
      Apple,

      [FruitAttribute(typeof(Orange))]
      Orange,

      [FruitAttribute(typeof(Banana))]
      Banana
  }
```

now you can rewrite your CreateFruit method like this:

```
  Fruit CreateFruit(Fruits fruits)
  {
      var type = fruits.GetType();
      var memberInfo = type.GetMember(fruits.ToString())[0];
      var fruitAttribute = memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes<FruitAttribute().First();
      return (Fruit)Activator.CreateInstance(fruitAttribute.Type);
  }
```

Comment: I like the attribute-approach, however it seems pretty redundant to apply the enum-value *and* the related type. Maybe better go for some cnaming-convention here.

Comment: Maybe the reverse relation would be better where `Fruit` inheritors have the `FruitAttribute` with the appropriate enum parameter.